# XAML detect when users's mouse leaves Silverlight window

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Does XAML provide a way to detect if the user's mouse cursor has left the Silverlight window? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is.

Assuming the the MainPage is your RootVisual and you've added a reference for System.Windows.Browser assembly then the following code should work.

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{      
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //objSilverlight is the <object> tag id
        var element = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("objSilverlight");
        element.AttachEvent("onmouseout", new EventHandler(HandleMouseOut));
    }

    public void HandleMouseOut(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        //handle your event here
    }
}
```

Basically the .Net event handler is being attached to the onmouseout DOM event in the Html object element that contains the silverlight plugin.